# Issue with multiple records of the same subdocument returned for MongoDb and Python

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado, pymongo

I'm getting this strange issue when getting back the results of a object with subdocuments from a Mongo database using Python and pymongo.

I have a document with a list of sub documents, e.g.

```
User: {
    "_id": ....
    hats: [{"colour": "blue" }]
}
```

I query this using find_one(). It returns back the details of the document and that one sub document record. However, next I do the query I get back two "hats", the second being a duplicate of the first. With the next I get back three "hats" and in continues on like that.

If I restart the application, "count" above is reset, so the find_one() query returns one sub document again.

There is definitely only one sub document record in the database, so that isn't the issue. It must be doing something weird in terms of in memory stuff.

I am using the Python "Tornado" framework, the application is a tornado.wsgi.WSGIApplication. Every time a new request comes it should be opening up a new connection.

The request handler does something along the lines of

```
class Handler(RequestHandler):
    def initialize(self):
        self.db = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
```

I'm really baffled about what it could be.

Comment: We'll need more info to help debug. Can you show the "find_one" call and a few lines of code around it? You mention a "count" but there's no "count" field in your example, so you're not showing us the relevant code.

Comment: The count I was referring to the number of duplicate sub documents. Not a database call. The find one all isn't complicated at all, its just .find_one({"_id": as_objectid(lobby_id)}). And as_objectid just a function with "return None if value is None else ObjectId(str(value))"

Comment: Thanks John. So far, nothing you've shared points me to a solution, so if you could actually paste the code that does the find_one, and any looping code outside of that? You wrote, "next I do the query I get back two hats", so what triggers an additional query? This isn't a known bug in MongoDB or PyMongo, so I'm looking to see enough of *your* code that I can see the bug.

Comment: Yes, your wording isn't helping. Need to look at your code. Especially this paragraph of yours >>>>> I query this using find_one(). It returns back the details of the document and that one sub document record. However, next I do the query I get back two "hats", the second being a duplicate of the first. With the next I get back three "hats" and in continues on like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately it was nothing to do with MongoDb.

For each collection type in the database I had a model class. With this I could decouple to exact details of how the data is stored from how it is returned from the server.

```
class User(ModelBase):
    name = None
    hats = []

@staticmethod
def from_db(document):
    model = User()
    model.name = document.get("name")

    hats = document.get("hats", list())
    from document in hats:
        hat = Hat.from_db(document)
        model.hats.append(hat)
    return model
```

The problem is that I defined the properties on the model directly instead of setting up in the init function.

That is

```
class User(ModelBase):
    name = None
    hats = []
```

instead of

```
class User(ModelBase):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.hats = []
```

I thought that they were equivalent, however it seems when variables are set on the class directly they are static variables shared between all instances of the class. So when I added a Hat to the list for one User object, the next User object had that Hat already in the list and added another one.